# Sentry: Non-Error exception captured with keys: [...]

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

Using Sentry on react-native with Expo, totally new to Sentry and relatively new to all other pieces of this stack. In some places in my code I am trying to use Sentry to capture errors that are returned from various frameworks, in other words they are *not* native JS Error objects. This is how it's invoked in my code:

`Sentry.Native.captureException(error);`

From the Sentry documentation itself, it says pretty clearly that capturing non-Error objects should be fine, and that the only issue is that you may be missing a stack trace for those:

> You can pass an Error object to captureException() to get it captured as event. It's also possible to pass non-Error objects and strings, but be aware that the resulting events in Sentry may be missing a stack trace. ([Link](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/usage/))

But what I see when one of these events triggers, in the Sentry dashboard, is only the following:

> Non-Error exception captured with keys: code, details, hint, message

It gives me this message, which is expected. Yes, my code captured a non-Error object with exactly those properties. But it doesn't tell me what the actual object is that was captured, just the keys. What about... the values of all those properties in the object?

Is there a different/better way to fully capture non-Error objects in Sentry? I don't care about the fact that the stack trace is missing, but I do care about actually seeing the whole object (keys and properties) in the Sentry dashboard for the objects I'm capturing, not just the keys.